# Rotativa quit working with CSS files in .NET Core project on server

Tags: c#, css, .net-core, rotativa

I previously had Rotativa working to create a PDF of a partial view using the `ViewAsPdf()` function. The function still renders a PDF and the data is still correct, however for some reason the CSS and images contained on the view no longer make it to the PDF. No changes were made to the server or IIS that I am aware of other than installing a certificate for HTTPS using win-acme. Any idea why this would happen? The views themselves work fine and populate with images and CSS.

The .NET Core project is compiled to target Windows x64 and is self contained (not dependent on the server having the correct framework) although .NET Core Hosting Bundle is installed on the server.

I have searched all over for a solution and tried:
Reinstalling Visual C++ (wkhtmltopdf relies on a few .dlls from it)

Downloaded the most current version of wkhtmltopdf and placed the .exe in the Rotativa folder under wwwroot

modified C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to uncomment out

```
#localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Changed the link to the css. Currently I have tried:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cards/cardBase.css" media="screen" />`
and
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/cards/cardBase.css")" media="screen" />`

Neither of these resolved the issue. Before it "broke" the razor syntax call to Url.Content("~pathtocss") worked great.

We even went as far as to spin up another VM and start from scratch all with the same results.

At this point I am hitting a wall for ideas, every other aspect of the app works correctly.

When I attempt to debug this in Visual Studio on localhost everything works great as well. Its almost like there is a permissions issue I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue had to do with IIS. I had the bindings of the site set to the IP of the machine itself, changing this to "All Unassigned Addresses" fixed the issue. I assume this has to do with localhost not being able to point at itself with a 127.0.0.1 IP. Hope this helps someone out at some point.